# 2 semi circle seekarc around a button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout which should look like this.

[image]

**I am using TriggerTrap/SeekArc from [github](https://github.com/TriggerTrap/SeekArc). Here is my xml.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.triggertrap.sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekArcContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
            android:id="@+id/seekArc1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            seekarc:arcColor="#808080"
            seekarc:clockwise="true"
            seekarc:max="500"
            seekarc:progressColor="@android:color/white"
            seekarc:rotation="275"
            seekarc:startAngle="0"
            seekarc:sweepAngle="175"
            seekarc:thumb="@drawable/custom_seek_arc_control_selector"
            seekarc:touchInside="false" />


        <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
            android:id="@+id/seekArc2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            seekarc:arcColor="#808080"
            seekarc:clockwise="true"
            seekarc:max="500"
            seekarc:progressColor="@android:color/white"
            seekarc:rotation="95"
            seekarc:startAngle="0"
            seekarc:sweepAngle="175"
            seekarc:thumb="@drawable/custom_seek_arc_control_selector"
            seekarc:touchInside="false" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/scrubber_pressed"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the problem is, since I am using frame layout, only one seekarc is clickable.
**If I change the seekarc to linear layout, the whole layout gets distorted like this.**

[image]

Now everything is clickable but the design is finished. Can anyone please tell me how to make it work such that the **button as well as both seekarc are touchable and also the design remains unaffected.**

Comment: Whew, offering 51,5% of your reputation. You sure want to have an answer

Comment: Yes.! I need the answer.

Comment: @Akshat There are other layouts in Android besides LinearLayout and FrameLayout. You should use a RelativeLayout in your case and position your two seekbars such@ that the two of them are positioned vertically (use layout_below or layout_above on one of the seekbars).

Comment: Since the `SeekArc` views seem to be taking the space of the whole circle regardless of the visible arc, you will probably need to extend `FrameLayout` and override the touch dispatcher to dispatch the events to the correct child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestion by @corsair992 is very good. However, reimplementing `onTouchEvent()` in a `FrameLayout` descendant is not as easy at it sounds, since it's a very complex method with many special conditions.

In this particular case, the problem is that the `FrameLayout` contains two `SeekArc` views, and the one in the foreground is consuming all touch events. Therefore, altering `SeekArc` itself to ignore events that do not belong to it seems like a much simpler alternative. If `SeekArc.ounTouchEvent()` returns false for these "unwanted" touches, then its FrameLayout parent will attempt passing the event to its other child -- exactly what we want.

Therefore, the solution is to change it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (isUnwantedTouch(event))
        return false;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    // ... same as before
}
```

Where the `isUnwantedTouch()` method is:

```
protected boolean isUnwantedTouch(MotionEvent event)
{
    return (ignoreTouch(event.getX(), event.getY()) ||
            getProgressForAngle(getTouchDegrees(event.getX(), event.getY())) == INVALID_PROGRESS_VALUE);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer - it is definitely easier/better to override the touch handling logic at the `View` level. However, these seem to be private methods that you're calling, so the library source itself will need to be patched for this. On the other hand, there doesn't seem to be any recent development on it, nor does it seem to published as an AAR, so that shouldn't present much problem.

Comment: @corsair992 Yes, the library is in "Eclipse format", so you need to include the source and compile it as a library project anyway. And I would think this is actually an improvement/bugfix on the library itself, irrespective of the particular use case. :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug for a touch-interactive`View` to handle it's touch events, regardless of whether the area is clickable or not. The real issue is that there doesn't seem to be an option for the `SeekArc` to confine it's size to a semicircle. jmols has provided an interesting workaround to that.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to @matiash approach, you can also, you can also wrap the SeekArcs in a new FrameLayout container to avoid the arcs from overlapping in the first place.

Downside is that this increases your view nesting hierarchy, but on the upside you don't have to make any code changes or touch the library code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.triggertrap.sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekArcContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="150dp">

            <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
                android:id="@+id/seekArc1"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                seekarc:arcColor="#808080"
                seekarc:clockwise="true"
                seekarc:max="500"
                seekarc:progressColor="@android:color/white"
                seekarc:rotation="275"
                seekarc:startAngle="0"
                seekarc:sweepAngle="175"
                seekarc:thumb="@drawable/custom_seek_arc_control_selector"
                seekarc:touchInside="false" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
                android:id="@+id/seekArc2"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="20dp"
                seekarc:arcColor="#808080"
                seekarc:clockwise="true"
                seekarc:max="500"
                seekarc:progressColor="@android:color/white"
                seekarc:rotation="95"
                seekarc:startAngle="0"
                seekarc:sweepAngle="175"
                seekarc:thumb="@drawable/custom_seek_arc_control_selector"
                seekarc:touchInside="false" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/scrubber_pressed"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting - I wasn't aware that the layout classes allowed their children to be drawn out of their bounds. Neat solution.

Comment: The other downside I see is that this solution is designed for a particular screen layout. The other one works "as is" no matter how the arcs are arranged (or even for any number of them instead of two).

Comment: @matiash: A generic solution should ideally deal with changing the measuring logic in the `SeekArc` view to allow it to fit it's bounds to the contents. Even your solution still requires a `FrameLayout` or other custom layout for overlapping the views, although it _would_ be easier to use that as a generic solution.